# Don't make functions within a loop, .then should return a value or throw

Tags: javascript, node.js

I currently have a function I'm writing in javascript.  I am hitting domo's api and fetching each separate page of data sets until there is nothing else to grab inside of a do while loop.  ESLINTR is yelling at me however for the following: Don't make functions within a loop, and .then should return a value or throw an error.  I'm unsure of how to go about stifling these errors.  the code is as follows:

```
  const getExistingDatasets = async () => {
    let results = 0
    let offSet = -50

    do {
      offSet = offSet + 50
      await axios
        .get(`https://api.domo.com/v1/datasets`, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: auth,
            Accept: 'application/json'
          },
          params: {
            offset: offSet
          }
        })
        .then(r => {
          results = r.data.length
          const data = r.data
          data.map(data => getDatasetColumns(data.id, data.name))
          console.log(results)
        })
    } while (results > 49)
  }

  getExistingDatasets()
```

Comment: see the code that begins like `.then(r => {` - it's a function created inside a loop and it doesn't return value - but don't mix async/await with .then ... simply `let r = await axios.get(....); let results = r.data.length;` etc

Comment: instead of creating a function inside of the loop what do i need to do?

Comment: Fix your editor settings. Your endless loop looks like a problem. Keeps going as long as results are more than 49 and you don't have `maxRecords` set in `params` *(although I'm not sure if there's a default)*. Why would you need that do while loop anyways? If there is no `maxRecords` do you get all the records? If so, loop over the results inside the `.then` function.

Comment: @StackSlave - what endless loop? the loop will end once results < 50 ...

Comment: I've not used `axios`. If that `.then` fired right away, and the results were the same and over 50, I figured that could happen. My bad. Anyway you cut it, that loop looks like a bad idea, since you are testing the while based on an Asynchronous result that may or may not be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start, you should avoid mixing async/await with promise .then - doing so in this case will fix both issues

```
const getExistingDatasets = async() => {
  let results = 0;
  let offSet = -50;
  const handleData = data => 
      data.forEach(item => getDatasetColumns(item.id, item.name));
  do {
    offSet = offSet + 50;
    let r = await axios
      .get(`https://api.domo.com/v1/datasets`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: auth,
          Accept: 'application/json'
        },
        params: {
          offset: offSet
        }
      });
    results = r.data.length;
    handleData(r.data);
    console.log(results)
  } while (results > 49)
}

getExistingDatasets();
```

edit: added "handleData" function

Comment: Lintr is still yelling at me for the unexpected await inside a loop, can i remove the await at this point? and then when I pass data.id and data.name into getDatasetColumns i get the warning about don't make functions within a loop

Comment: @RobTerrell No, because you *want* a sequential asynchronous operation here, you should disable that "no-await-in-loop" rule. It has too many false positives.

Comment: @RobTerrell However, your linter should complain about `data.map(data => getDatasetColumns(data.id, data.name))` which creates an array that's never used anywhere. Use a loop or `forEach` instead.

Comment: @RobTerrell *Lintr is **still** yelling at me for the unexpected await inside a loop* ... you never mentioned that in the question, so it's not *still yelling*, it's a new warning

Comment: everything in the .then is the issue in the question so it's still the same warning

Comment: using a forEach produces the same results as well which seems confusing to me

Comment: try creating a function (outside the loop of course) that takes `data` and executes  `data.forEach(data => getDatasetColumns(data.id, data.name))` - see if `lintr` stops complaining now - see edited answser